# Why this cubic surface just can find 3 lines?

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, cubics

I often heard that each smooth cubic surface contains even $27$ straight lines, such as [this statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_surface#27_lines_on_a_cubic_surface). So I use the *Mathematica* plot the equation with [this code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/279504/21532):$$\begin{align}1 + 54 x y z - &9 (x + y + z) + 126 (x y + x z + y z) - 9 (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) - \\&189 (x^2 y + x y^2 + x^2 z + y^2 z + x z^2 + y z^2) +    81 (x^3 + y^3 + z^3)=0\end{align}$$
[image]

But when I solve a cubic equation, like $x^3 + 3 y^3 + z^3-2 x^2 + 5 x y - x + 7=0$ Now I only just find $3$ lines:

[image]

Is this surface not smooth? Or is the theorem wrong? Or am I getting it wrong? How to understand this phenomenon?

Comment: The 27 lines are guaranteed in complex space, looks like. They will not all necessarily be real, and thus visible.

Comment: @DanUznanski I don't think I've seen that request(complex space) anywhere else. All I saw was a book that said "smooth"

Comment: Wikipedia uses the phrase "algebraically closed field" which describes complex numbers but not real numbers.

Comment: @DanUznanski What condition does the cubic equation satisfy when it has 27 *real lines* in

Comment: Look at https://blogs.ams.org/visualinsight/2016/02/15/27-lines-on-a-cubic-surface/#:~:text=The%20special%20virtue%20of%20the,rather%20than%20a%20complex%20surface.&text=real%20solutions%20of-,x31%2Bx32%2Bx33%2B,3%2Bx4)3.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Is there an easy way to tell how many lines are on this surface($x^3 + 3 y^3 + z^3-2 x^2 + 5 x y - x + 7=0$)?

Comment: I take it you mean real lines? I do not know. One of $3,7,15,27$ it appears. I think you'll have to look at what Schläfli proved.